# Linking website homepage to Facebook community page

Tags: html, facebook-like

I'm working on a website www.lunker.com. We want to have a Like button on the homepage for the website, but we also plan on building a Facebook community page to promote the website business. How can I link the website homepage Like button to the community page so that the counter includes users who like it from both lunker.com and on the Facebook page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple- simply add the facebook like snippet into the page where you want it to be shown.
Facebook provides a "like button generator" here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
Once it's done, you can copy and paste the snippet code into your HTML.

Comment: Do I have the HTML code in the Like button point to www.lunker.com or to our Facebook community page: https://www.facebook.com/catchmylunker ?

Comment: I've confirmed that pointing to the URL of your Facebook community page is the way to do it. So Instead of having my URL point to http://www.lunker.com I'm having the like button point to the community page at https://www.facebook.com/catchmylunker